# Acknowledge professional/paid language correction service?

Tags: ethics, acknowledgement

I am a non-native English speaker and had a paper manuscript corrected by a professional/paid agency. The agency only corrected language mistakes and did not do any content-related work. Should I acknowledge this when publishing the paper and if so, how?

Comment: The area of research is important here.  In some areas (humanities) phrasing, denotation and connotation are critical.  In an extreme case, say the translation of a poem, the translator might need to be coauthor.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You raise a point here! However, in this specific instance, the main output of the scientific work is quantitative and the key results should not be influenced by the language corrections.

Answer (score 5):

You could do so in an "acknowledgements" section or even a footnote. But, if they haven't contributed to the content (ideas) of the paper, then it isn't required. But it is polite. Don't make it seem like you are giving them free advertising, however.

And an editor or reviewer of a journal might ask you to remove it, depending on their rules. They might have valuable advice in any case.